# CodeVisionAVR V2.03.9 not running and error message

Tags: windows-7, installation

I tried install this software in windows 7 (64 bit)

But when running the application,I see this error.

[image]

(I am new to this software,But before I had installed this software on Windows7 And the software run without problems)

I do not know Where is the problem this time?

thank you for your help or hint.

Comment: Are you running the program as an [administrator](http://www.techsupportalert.com/content/three-tips-running-programs-administrator-windows-7.htm)? Did you check if the file `IOPORT.SYS` is in `C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\DRIVERS`?

Comment: @terdon yes, I'm running the program in adminstrator.I can not find "IOPORT.SYS" (I see "drivers" in C:\Windows\System32\Drivers but there is not this file)

Comment: @terdon: Forgive me,what is "IOPORT.SYS " ... Do I need to remove this file?

Comment: @terdon Forgive me ... Do I need to download and install this(IOPORT.SYS ) file?

Comment: I don't know, I've never heard of it before. However, google seems to have many many hits with exactly this problem (for example, [here](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_vista-hardware/cannot-start-ioport-driver-make-sure-you-have/2c929e63-48ad-46e3-9300-2930d931a79d)). You should be ble to find an answer if you look around a bit.

Comment: Yes I saw it.I found the answer to my problem.thank you @terdon

Comment: Glad to hear you sorted it out. Please post your solution as an answer and accept it.

Comment: @terdon OK :), post my answer. Thank you for guide me And I'm glad you're here. -;<@

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer for my problem.

this software Only be installed in windows NT4,2000,xp,vista, **seven 32 bit** (this software Not installed in win7 64 bit)

and

Also can not install or found on Windows7 the file "IOPORT.SYS".

Thank you everybody :)